# R: How to use Bing free tier web search using R

Tags: r, bing

Assuming user provided card and phone and has valid Azure account. Created a free tier service. (has key and endpoint, something like xyz.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0

Using free tier (3 searchers per second and max per month or so) (see here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/ )

Is it a GET or POST call and what are the right header parameters?
They only have Python example that is not working.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/python

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/blob/master/python/Search/BingWebSearchv7.py

The questions is how to do it in R.

This code does not work

```
library(httr)
token='xxxxx'
server='https://xxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0/'
url=paste0(server,'search')
response = GET(url = url, 
               authenticate('',token, type = 'basic'))
response
res = content(response, encoding = 'json')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `/search` endpoint, a `GET` request with a non-empty search parameter (`q`) is required.

`Basic Authentication` is not supported at all. Instead, as shown in the Python example, an HTTP header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` containing your subscription key is required.

So, I succeeded with the following code. It should work for you too.

```r
library(httr)

server = "https://xxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0/"
token = "subscription key for Bing Search APIs v7"
search_term = "search term"
url = paste0(server, "search")

response = GET(url = url, 
    query = list(q = search_term), 
    add_headers(`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` = token)
)
res = content(response, encoding = "json")
res
```

See [Web Search API v7 reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference) for more information about headers and query parameters.

Comment: thanks. Count of results can be seen by `res$webPages$totalEstimatedMatches` also good is `jsonview::json_tree_view(res)`